# Object.clone() in javap when using covariant return types in Java

Tags: java, javap, covariant-return-types

I am reading about [covariant return types in Java.](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/covariant-return-types-in-java) I wrote the following code:

A parent class:

```
package other;

public class Super implements Cloneable {

    @Override
    public Super clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Super) super.clone();
    }

}
```

A child class:

```
package other;

public class Sub extends Super {

    @Override
    public Sub clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Sub) super.clone();
    }
}
```

How I use it:

```
package com.sample;

import other.Sub;
import other.Super;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Super aSuper = new Super();
        Super bSuper = aSuper.clone();
        System.out.println(aSuper == bSuper); // false

        Sub aSub = new Sub();
        Sub bSub = aSub.clone();
        System.out.println(aSub == bSub); // false
    }
}
```

If it's OK to return a subtype when overriding a method (as you see, that's what I do with `clone()` in `Super` and `Sub`), why do I see `Object.clone` in `Super` and `Sub` when I run `javap -p Super.class` and `javap -p Sub.class`, respectively?

The result of `javap -p Super.class`:

```
Compiled from "Super.java"
public class other.Super implements java.lang.Cloneable {
  public other.Super();
  public other.Super clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
  public java.lang.Object clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
}
```

The result of `javap -p Sub.class`:

```
Compiled from "Sub.java"
public class other.Sub extends other.Super {
  public other.Sub();
  public other.Sub clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
  public other.Super clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
  public java.lang.Object clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask, when the article you linked explicitly talks about **`javac` generated methods** (also known a *bridge* methods) in the section named "**How is this implemented?**"? Did you actually *read* the linked article?

Answer (score 0):

clone method belongs to class `Object` We can override this method .But in order to call this method  Java Runtime requires us to indicate that this class will clone its object using clone method which makes  a field-for-field copy of instances of that class .

This indication is done buy using marker interface `Cloneable` (marker interfaces have no method they are used just to indicate a specific thing to compiler and JVM) .

In class Super clone() method you are calling `super.clone()`  That is nothing but call to Object.clone() method because Object is direct super class of Super .

That explains why you see `java.lang.Object clone()` when you use `javap`

for more info read

[Cloneable ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)